# Best way to accomplish this drawing with Quartz 2D / Core Graphics?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, quartz-graphics

As the background for one of the views in my app, I'd like to draw a fairly simple rectangular border just inside its frame. This would essentially be a rectangular gradient: a black line around the frame, fading to white about 10-20 pixels in. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, Core Graphics doesn't provide rectangular gradients (either with `CGGradient` or `CGShading`). So I'm wondering what the best approach would be.

Two that occur to me:

1. Draw a series of concentric rectangles, each subsequent one lighter in color, and inset by 1px on each side. I can't think of a simpler approach, but I have to do all of the gradient calculations myself, and it might be a lot of graphics operations.
2. Use `CGGradient` in linear mode, once for each side. But for this to work, I think I'd need to set up a trapezoidal clipping area for each side first, so that the gradients would be mitered at the corners.

Seems like there *should* be a way to use path stroking to do this, but it doesn't seem like there's a way to define a pattern that's oriented differently on each side.

Comment: Using a CGGradient for each edge will be quicker, but you could use a UIImage as a cache if that's still too slow (draw to the UIImage once, and then draw the image onto the view when needed)

Comment: Yeah, I think that no matter what approach I take to the drawing, caching an image with the results is probably going to be a good idea. But I kind of like the idea of doing the drawing procedurally, rather than shipping a PNG in the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with option #2:

> Use CGGradient in linear mode, once for each side. But for this to work, I think I'd need to set up a trapezoidal clipping area for each side first, so that the gradients would be mitered at the corners.

Using `NSBezierPath` to create the trapezoidal regions would be fairly straightforward, and you would only have to perform four drawing operations.

Here's the basic code for creating the left side trapezoidal region:

```
NSRect outer = [self bounds];
NSPoint outerPoint[4];
outerPoint[0] = NSMakePoint(0, 0);
outerPoint[1] = NSMakePoint(0, outer.size.height);
outerPoint[2] = NSMakePoint(outer.size.width, outer.size.height);
outerPoint[3] = NSMakePoint(outer.size.width, 0);

NSRect inner = NSInsetRect([self bounds], borderSize, borderSize);
NSPoint innerPoint[4];
innerPoint[0] = inner.origin;
innerPoint[1] = NSMakePoint(inner.origin.x,
                            inner.origin.y + inner.size.height);
innerPoint[2] = NSMakePoint(inner.origin.x + inner.size.width,
                            inner.origin.y + inner.size.height);
innerPoint[3] = NSMakePoint(inner.origin.x + inner.size.width,
                            inner.origin.y);

NSBezierPath leftSidePath = [[NSBezierPath bezierPath] retain];
[leftSidePath moveToPoint:outerPoint[0]];
[leftSidePath lineToPoint:outerPoint[1]];
[leftSidePath lineToPoint:innerPoint[1]];
[leftSidePath lineToPoint:innerPoint[0]];
[leftSidePath lineToPoint:outerPoint[0]];

// ... etc.

[leftSidePath release];
```

Comment: Speaking as someone who (obviously?) hasn't done a lot of graphics programming on the iPhone (or Mac) yet... is there a reason to prefer NSBezierPath? Most examples I've seen concentrate on the Core Graphics APIs.

Comment: Well, I used it here because I've used it before, so know that it works. :) It is entirely possible that Core Graphics can do it better. No harm in giving it a try, but be sure to profile your code to see if you are getting a measurable performance increase (or if you actually need one, for that matter).

Comment: This isn't exactly the code I ended up with, but it's petty similar. Never did come up with a better solution than drawing four trapezoids.

Answer (score 0):

something like this could also work.
basically: instead of using clipping paths, simply use blendmode.
and in this example the gradient is cached in a CGLayer.

```
 CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGColorSpaceRef cspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

 CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
 CGContextFillRect(ctx,self.bounds);

 CGFloat w = self.bounds.size.width;
 CGFloat h = self.bounds.size.height;
 CGFloat dh = (w-h)/2;

 CGLayerRef l = CGLayerCreateWithContext(ctx,CGSizeMake(h,48.0f),NULL);
 CGContextRef lctx = CGLayerGetContext(l);

 float comp[] = { .2,.5,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
 CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(cspace, comp, NULL, 2);
 CGContextDrawLinearGradient(lctx, gradient,CGPointMake(0,0),CGPointMake(0,48), 0);

 CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
 CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx,kCGBlendModeDarken);
 for(int n=1;n<5;n++)
 {
  CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx,w/2.0,h/2.0);
  CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, M_PI_2);
  CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx,-w/2.0,-h/2.0);
  CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(ctx,CGPointMake((n%2)*dh,(n%2)*-dh),l);
 }
 CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
```